# Genymotion error Cannot find Genymotion in the specified path

Tags: genymotion

[image]

On my mac ,I have installed Genymotion.when trying to location Genymotion.app I get this error: "Cannot find Genymotion in the specified path"

this is the path i entered for genymotion.app: 
/Applications/Genymotion.app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player.app/Contents/MacOS/player
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player.app